# logging issues datadog on google kubernetes engine

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, datadog

I am building a monitoring environment with data dock in GKE environment.

I have configured datadog helm-chart with logs set to enabled. At this time, doesn't the Datadog agent automatically get the logs of all pods on the Node?

As shown below, it seems that logs are being collected only when the annotation must be attached to the Pods you want to collect logs from

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "chart.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    {{- include "chart.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
    tags.datadoghq.com/env: "test-env"
    tags.datadoghq.com/service: "test-service"
    tags.datadoghq.com/version: 0.0.1
spec:
    ....
```

In this case, what if you want to automatically get the logs of all Pods floating in the cluster?

I tried allowing datadog agent to work and show logs dashboard in datadog web

Answer (score -1):

try to enable in datadog values file under logs part-

[logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMYZA.png)

Comment: It does not work